# Can't make Discord bot get online

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to code my Java bot in Python, but I can't make the bot appears online.

When I run it with `python3` it doesn't raise an error, but nothing happens and there is no bot connection in the server.

I have already installed -env and discord.py.

Code I used:

`bot.py`

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(token)
```

`.env`

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: You posted your token. Shouldn't it be a secret?

Comment: I used one as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `token` is returning `None`. First make sure your .env file is in the same directory:

```
├── .env
└── bot.py
```

Then pass your .env file to `load_dotenv()`:

```py
import os
import discord

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("config.env")
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(token)
```

Comment: No quotes are needed it should just be `DISCORD_TOKEN=token`

Comment: Maybe is there something wrong here. I am a Python Rookie so thanks for your time solving this silly stuff [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urx6q.jpg

Comment: using python: line 4, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

Comment: python3 returns none

Comment: You need to install the dotenv module, `pip install python-dotenv`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in c:\****\****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.14.0)

Comment: I'm not sure how Anaconda works, looks like it comes with it's own terminal. Can you try using `pip install python-dotenv` in the Anaconda Prompt?. However, as a temporary fix, you can just hard-code your token into `client.run()` like so `client.run("token here")` . Make sure to remove anything dealing with dotenv or you will get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied in Anaconda prompt. I removed all dotenv and run again but I recieve what seems an error:

Comment: Download and install this certificate here: https://crt.sh/?id=2835394
--> It can be installed by double clicking the file and installing it to Local Computer, download link location: https://beans-took-my-kids.reeee.ee/38qB2n.png